# WebGL parameter - "must be zero" - why provide it?

Tags: webgl

`framebufferTexture2D` has several arguments of which last one is `level`.

> A GLint specifying the mipmap level of the texture image to be attached. Must be 0.

If it must be zero, why do we have to specify it?

Comment: Seems it was "copy-pasted" from the OpenGL ES 2 spec: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glFramebufferTexture2D.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's based on the [OpenGL ES 2 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glFramebufferTexture2D.xml), and doing it this way enables better forwards compatibility. There's no logical reason why the mipmap `level` *has* to be zero (aside from the fact the spec currently doesn't support it), so it enables future versions of the spec the ability to widen the scope of that argument and allow other values without changing the method signature.

[This has indeed already happened in OpenGL ES 3, which no longer requires the parameter to be zero in all cases](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glFramebufferTexture2D.xhtml).

Comment: That's one way to look at it. Another is that ES inherits from OpenGL where that parameter as been since forever. Similarly on `TexImage2D` the `border` parameter which has to be zero and on `UniformMatrix` the `transpose` parameter which has to be false in ES 2.0 is inherited from OpenGL

Comment: @gman Yup, I'd say that's also a valid assumption - there's always a certain amount of guesswork when it comes to these things!